# Using statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose, my trend line does not cover the entire time period of the data. any words of advice?

Tags: time-series, decomposition

I am trying to do a time series decomposition using this[1](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-from-scratch-decomposing-time-series-data-7b7ad0c30fe7) article as a guide--it uses statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose. However, the trend line I get does not extend to the beginning or end of my data's time period, it only sits in the middle. is this expected? any ideas around what I may be doing incorrectly?

I would appreciate any direction!

Comment: Apparently statsmodel needs at least (or maybe even more) then 2 full season. So if you have monthly data, you might need more than 24 months of data.